# Can't install Lutris in terminal

Tags: 20.04, downloads

Every command I use can’t install anything as I keep getting error code. I am using 20.04 and used commands such as

```
sudo add-apt-repository papa:lutris-team/lutris 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install lutris
```

at the end of every failed download I get

```
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done 
Correcting dependancies… Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
Libvdpaul 
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded. 276 not fully installed or removed 
Need to get 0 B/25.6 KB of archives 
After this operation, 109 KB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? (Y/N) I click Yes 
(Reading database … 160926 files and directories currently installed.
Preparing to unpack …/libvdpau1_1.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb …
Unpacking libvdpau1: amd64 (1.3-1Ubuntu2) …
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (—unpack): 
Trying to overwrite shared ‘/etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg’, which is different from other instances of package bvdpau1:amd64
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var /cache/ apt/ archives/ libvdpau1_1.3-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)”
```

Tried installing Lutris and Komorebi and was unsuccessful.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the version of Ubuntu you’re using (2) the command you’re using to install the software (3) any additional information about the error that might be useful. As it stands, there is insufficient information here for anyone to offer a solution.

Comment: We need to see the entire output. The summary at the end does not contain enough detail to offer helpful advice.

Comment: Is this good enough?

Comment: I did find this which may help:  https://www.tecmint.com/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-in-ubuntu/